# Why doesn't \r\n / CRLF result in the line being reread in perpetuity?

Tags: newline, control-characters

If `CR` (`\r`) moves the cursor to the front of the line, and `LF` (`\n`) moves the cursor to the next line, why is `LF` consumed, rather than the line being re-read?

e.g.: `hello world\r\n`

- Read `hello world`, cursor is at `d`
- `\r` is seen, move to front of line(?)
- We don't reread `hello world`, but the cursor is now looking at... `h`? (I would think that `\r` would now result in us re-reading `hello world`.
- `\n` is seen, move to next line

To me, this functionality implies that the cursor is not necessarily related to the consumption of the file/text/buffer, but how this all cooperates is not immediately apparent to me, either.

What gives?

Comment: Perhaps a bit of a misunderstanding, there is no instruction between `\r` and `\n` so while it's true that the cursor returns to the beginning of the line, the next instruction is not to read or consume the line (again) but to move to the next line.  In general, You don't necessarily consume a letter at a time (but a buffer-length, typically a line's worth, at a time)

Comment: What blurfus said. The `d` or `\r` or `\n` is just a byte when it is stored. The interpretation you describe for `\r` is a behavioural artifact of the tty, not inherent to the byte itself. The next byte after the `\r` is not an `h`.

Comment: Control characters like CR or LF can move the cursor when you *write* them to a *device that has a cursor* and can move it, such as a terminal. Reading these bytes has no effect on a cursor, if any. A disk file has no cursor. (The current file position is not a cursor.)

Comment: Thanks folks, these notes are helpful. I'd like to give _someone_ credit for answering this, if any of you would like to submit an "answer".